# Open a copy of the same window using WPF

Tags: wpf

I am working with a WPF application.I have two text boxes and a button in my first window.Based on some DB operations i need to open the copy of the first window(if possible open like a new tab) provided both windows can be accessed simultaneously.I used

```
var MainWindow = new MainWindow();
MainWindow.ShowDialog();
```

and

```
var MainWindow = new MainWindow();
MainWindow.Show();
```

both of them doesnt meet my expectations.Can anyone help me.

Comment: You have shown two identical code examples.

Comment: Please tick whichever question you feel answered your problem, so that other users know that this question has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `ShowDialog()`, it opens a single modal dialog that is expected to be closed when complete.

If you want to open multiple windows and not block form control, try using `Show()` instead.

```
var window = new MainWindow();
window.Show();
```

Comment: It is working.Is there any option to open it as a tabbed window ?

Comment: No, but if you want tabs, you should have a `TabControl`, change your window to instead be a `UserControl`, and load the controls into each tab as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to read all of the relating pages on MSDN so that you can learn how everything works.

For the `Show` method:

> Opens a window and returns without waiting for the newly opened window to close.

For the `ShowDialog` method:

> Opens a window and returns only when the newly opened window is closed.

From the Remarks section of the [Window.Show Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.show.aspx) page:

> When the Window class is instantiated, it is not visible by default. Show shows a window and returns immediately, without waiting for the window to be closed. Consequently, the opened window does not prevent users from interacting with other windows in the application. This type of window is called a modeless window. Common examples of modeless windows are properties windows, toolboxes, and palettes. To restrict a user to interacting with a specific window, the window must be opened by calling ShowDialog.
>
> Calling Show achieves the same end result as setting Visibility property of the Window object to Visible. However, there is a difference between the two from a timing perspective.

Therefore, for your solution, I would recommend that you use the `Show` method instead.

Comment: It is working.Is there any option to open it as a tabbed window ?

Comment: What is a tabbed `Window`? If you mean a `Window` that has a `TabControl` inside it, then how about adding a `TabControl` to the XAML inside the `Window`?